can't uninstall python 3.11.x on windows(no software/no path)
I'm having trouble uninstalling Python.

There's no app, so it can't be uninstalled.
There's no path, so it can't be uninstalled either.
So, if I want to install another version of Python, it will overlap and I won't be able to use its library.

Is there anyone who can help? Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/9azlv.png)
i tried to watch tutorial but didn't change anything

What's your python install source? Windows store or Python official website?

You can use the command where python to view path
